# SoapUI property transfer and xpath/xquery number formatting

Tags: xpath, formatting, xquery, soapui

I have this property-transfer in SoapUI:

```
declare namespace soapEnv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId
```

and lets say it returns **123456**. But I want **123457** (what I get +1)

I tried this:

```
declare namespace soapEnv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId + 1
```

but I get **123457.0** as a result. I tried some reformatting methods I found, but most possibly I did not use them in the correct way. I am quite new at this stuff.

I also tried this (with xquery):

```
declare namespace soapEnv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
let $x := //soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId
return $x
```

and tried several things with **$x** but everything I tried ended up with null or InvocationTargetException.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Well, I don't know what xpath version SoapUI is using.. I tried to find it but without much luck :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions, although I couldn't make them work :(
Maybe there is something wrong with my SoapUI because all xpath functions return null..

I made it work with groovy:

```
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )

loginResponse = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Login#Response")
loginResponse.declareNamespace( "soapEnv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" )
sessionIdStr = loginResponse.getNodeValue( "//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/sessionId" )
baseSequenceIdStr = loginResponse.getNodeValue( "//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId" )
sequenceIdStr = (baseSequenceIdStr.toInteger() + 1).toString()

createRequest = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Create#Request")
createRequest.declareNamespace( "soapEnv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" )
createRequest.setNodeValue( "//soapEnv:Header/SessionId", sessionIdStr )
createRequest.setNodeValue( "//soapEnv:Header/TransactionId", baseSequenceIdStr )
createRequest.setNodeValue( "//soapEnv:Header/SequenceId", sequenceIdStr )
createRequest.updateProperty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the value of `//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId + 1` is an integer, XPath [should not put in a decimal point](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) when converting it to a string.

But maybe in this case XPath is returning a number, and it's SoapUI that's converting it to a string, and using a decimal point.

I would first try **(updated)**:

```
string(//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId + 1)
```

This is to force the conversion to string to happen within XPath, so that SoapUI won't have a chance to do anything funny with a numeric value.

Alternatively, you could try

```
floor(//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId + 1)
```

or even

```
string(floor(...))
```

If that doesn't work, you could try

```
substring-before(//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId + 1, '.')
```

It's not very elegant, but it might work.

Comment: Thanks!  
I will try the first one tomorrow morning. As for the second one, the XML part that xpath (//soapEnv:Body/...) gets, is just an integer (always without any characters). Although, I don't know if it is represented as an integer, a string, or anything else.. Nonetheless, a 'dot' is not going to be there!

Comment: @Stefanos, I understand that the value of `//soapEnv:Body/LoginResponse/baseSequenceId` is always an integer. However, the decimal point is coming in somewhere. I'll add one more suggestion to my answer.

Comment: If your data is untyped (schema-less) then the result of the addition will be a double. XPath would format it as "1234567", but your host language may well format it with a ".0" at the end. So do the conversion to string in XPath, using the string() function.